# style для input type=file

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

есть кнопка инпут для изображений

```
<input type="file" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="photo">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для активации доступно всё поле btn-block, а не только сам input, но как сделать прозрачной белую кнопку, так чтоб "обзор..." и "файл не выбран" остались видимыми?

Comment: никак. обычно скрывают весь инпут полностью

Comment: По причинам безопасности, `input[type='file']` нельзя особо кастомизировать, дабы "не ввести пользователя в неведение на что он кликает".

Comment: @other кастомизировать можно все)

Comment: @NikitaSmith, я не сказал что совсем нельзя. Но бОльшую часть стилей этот вид инпута игнорирует.

Comment: @NikitaSmith, скрыть элемент - это не значит - кастомизировать :)

Comment: @Grundy Ну смотря как смотреть на это :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Применительно к бутстрапу есть замечательные аддоны от Jasny: [jasny-bootstrap](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/). В их составе - стилизованные fileinput'ы ([ссылка на документацию](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput)). Сам в своих проектах использую бутстрап и эти аддоны.

В случае с изображениями у меня такая верстка:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="media text-center fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
        <div class="media-object fileinput-new" data-trigger="fileinput"><span class="fa fa-photo fa-3x text-legend"></span></div>
        <div class="media-object fileinput-exists thumbnail fileinput-preview" data-trigger="fileinput"></div>
        <div class="media-body media-middle text-legend fileinput-new" data-trigger="fileinput">
            <div class="media-heading">Добавить фото</div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body media-middle text-muted fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">
            <div class="media-heading">Удалить фото</div>
        </div>
        <input accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" class="form-control-invisible" type="file" name="ad[photo]" id="ad_photo">
    </div>
</div>
```

Кажется, что ее много. Это нужно для вывода миниатюры выбранного в инпуте изображения и для смены кнопки "Добавить фото" на "Удалить фото".

Использую совместно с компонентом бутстрапа `.media` и [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) для иконки пустого инпута. Вместо `<span class="fa fa-photo fa-3x text-legend"></span>` вы можете просто вставить изображение через тег `<img>`.

В дополнение к стилям jasny-bootstrap, я стилизую конкретно этот инпут:

```
.fileinput {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.fileinput .thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: initial;
}

div[data-trigger='fileinput'],
div[data-dismiss='fileinput'] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.media.fileinput {
  background-color: #F7FAFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #CCD1C3;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 24px 30px;
}
.media.fileinput .media-heading {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.media.fileinput .thumbnail.fileinput-preview {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.media.fileinput .thumbnail.fileinput-preview img {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: initial;
}
.media.fileinput .fileinput-new .img-responsive {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #CCD1C3;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: initial;
}
.media.fileinput .media-left .thumbnail.fileinput-preview.shape-60px {
  margin: -12px 0;
}
.media.fileinput.text-center .thumbnail.fileinput-preview {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #CCD1C3;
  text-align: center;
}
```

В итоге получаю такой инпут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И он же с выбранным изображением:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Самое *красивое* и *разумное* решение, которое есть на данный момент:

[**Нажми на меня**](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomFileInputs/)

ps. Можете изменять все элементы на свой вкус

Comment: Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются тут.

Comment: @Other ты предлагаешь выложить все вариации? Я не против конечно, но весь объем я не смогу захватить в один ответ, а ресурс написал на простом английском и имеет доступное решение.

Comment: Я ничего не предлагаю, а только говорю что ответы-ссылки не любят, т. к. сторонний ресурс умрёт и Ваш ответ будет совершенно бесполезен.

Comment: @Other Я понял вас, домой приеду выложу кусок решения.